# Create a physics body with hole : bullet physics

Tags: ios, blender, bullet-physics, cocos3d

I am writing an iOS game, using bullet for physics, blender to create models, cocos3d as the game engine.

I have a model like this
[image]

Basically there is a plane, with a hole, and a UVSphere. Both were created in blender. What I am trying is to create a physics body along the vertices of the plane. So that when the UVSphere goes over the hole, it should fall through.

I am using `btBvhTriangleMeshShape` to create physics body along the vertices of this plane. code is given below

```
//GPlane stands for groundPlane :)
CC3MeshNode* gPlaneNode  = (CC3MeshNode*)[self getNodeNamed:@"GPlane"];

/*Get Vertex and indices data out from the .pod*/
float *gVertexData       = (float*)((CC3VertexArrayMesh*)gPlaneNode.mesh)
                                .vertexLocations.vertices;
GLushort* gIndices       = (GLushort*)((CC3VertexArrayMesh*)gPlaneNode.mesh)
                                .vertexIndices.vertices;
int gIndiceCount         = ((CC3VertexArrayMesh*)gPlaneNode.mesh)
                                .vertexIndices.vertexCount;

/*Create triangle mesh*/
btTriangleMesh* gTriangleMesh = new btTriangleMesh();
for (int i = 0; i < gIndiceCount; i+=3)
{
   unsigned int index1 = gIndices[i] * 6;
   unsigned int index2 = gIndices[i+1] * 6;
   unsigned int index3 = gIndices[i+2] * 6;
   gTriangleMesh->addTriangle(
      btVector3(gVertexData[index1] , gVertexData[index1+1], gVertexData[index1+2]),
      btVector3(gVertexData[index2] , gVertexData[index2+1], gVertexData[index2+2] ),
      btVector3(gVertexData[index3] , gVertexData[index3+1], gVertexData[index3+2]));
}

/*Create  a rigid body using this triangle mesh*/
btBvhTriangleMeshShape *gTriMeshShape   =   new
                          btBvhTriangleMeshShape(gTriangleMesh,true);
gTriMeshShape->setMargin(0.1);
btDefaultMotionState *groundMotionState =   
                new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0,0,0,1)
                                           ,btVector3(0,0.0,0)));
btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo groundRigidBodyCI(0
                   ,groundMotionState,gTriMeshShape,btVector3(0,0,0.0));
groundRigidBodyCI.m_restitution = 0.3;
btRigidBody *groundRigidBody = new btRigidBody(groundRigidBodyCI);
dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(groundRigidBody);
```

And I am adding the sphere to the scene like this

```
sphereNode    =   (CC3MeshNode*)[self getNodeNamed:@"Sphere"];
btCollisionShape *fallShape = new btSphereShape(1);
btDefaultMotionState *fallMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(
           btQuaternion(sphereNode.location.x,sphereNode.location.y
              ,sphereNode.location.z,1), btVector3(0,0,0)));
btScalar mass = 1.0;
btVector3 fallInertia(0,0,0);
fallShape->calculateLocalInertia(mass, fallInertia);
btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo fallRigidBodyCI(mass
                      ,fallMotionState,fallShape,fallInertia);
fallRigidBodyCI.m_restitution = 1.0;
fallRigidBody = new btRigidBody(fallRigidBodyCI);
fallRigidBody->setDamping(0.3,0.8);
dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(fallRigidBody);
```

To view the physics body, I use [bullet physics debug drawing method](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58513/bullet-physics-debug-drawing-not-working) and this is how it is drawn

[image]

As far as I can tell, physics body looks fine, the hole is there alright.

### My problem

It is simple. My ball just slide over the hold instead of falling through it. I expect with a mass and negative Y gravity, the ball to fall through the hole.

Ball is falling of the edge of the plane alright. So gravity is there.

Any idea?

Comment: Try cutting through the hole, making two separate meshes, like this > http://i.imgur.com/eeqkx7T.jpg

Comment: @GustavoMaciel That didn't help. It was the problem with the way I exported the sphere from blender. See my answer. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got this working. 
I changed the sphere adding code to this

```
CC3MeshNode *node =  (CC3MeshNode*)[self getNodeNamed:@"Sphere"];

//This was the magic step.. I don't know how 
//copying helped. But it did
CC3MeshNode *sphereNode = (CC3MeshNode*)[node copyWithName:@"someOtherName"];

sphereNode.location             =   cc3v(0.0, 1.0, 10);
[self addChild:sphereNode];

//Remove the original node, since we no longer need this.
[self removeChild:node];

//Now physics body.
btCollisionShape *fallShape = new btSphereShape(0.5);

//This line also different.. Compare with the code in question
btDefaultMotionState *fallMotionState 
     =  new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(
         sphereNode.location.x, sphereNode.location.y, sphereNode.location.z,1)
         ,btVector3(sphereNode.location.x,sphereNode.location.y
         ,sphereNode.location.z)));
btScalar mass  =   1.0;
btVector3 fallInertia(0,0,0);
fallShape->calculateLocalInertia(mass, fallInertia);
btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo fallRigidBodyCI(
                 mass,fallMotionState,fallShape,fallInertia);
fallRigidBodyCI.m_restitution   =   1.0;
btRigidBody* fallRigidBody =   new btRigidBody(fallRigidBodyCI);
fallRigidBody->setDamping(0.3,0.8);
dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(fallRigidBody);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the code side but within blender you can set the block with a whole in it to use mesh for the collision shape and the ball will fall through the hole.

Comment: @sambler My blender model had a hole in it. And physics body along the model got created correctly (you can see the second image in question). The problem was the physics body I created for the ball is got placed in a different location. But adding physics body like the one given in answer corrected the issue